# Nested TransactionScope() won't roll back

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

I am trying to make use of nested transactions in C# for the first time. In the past I've always wrapped my `SqlCommands` inside `SqlTransactions` inside `SqlConnections`. Something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(...))    
    using (SqlTransaction myTran = myCon.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (SqlCommand myCom1 = new SqlCommand("...", myCon, myTran))
        {
            ...
        }       
        using (SqlCommand myCom2 = new SqlCommand("...", myCon, myTran))
        {
            ...
        }
        .
        .
        .
        myTran.Commit();
    }
}
```

All of this, with the necessary `try...catch` handling of course so if an exception occurs anywhere inside the `SqlTransaction`, I know that none of the `SqlCommands` will be committed.

So I thought I'd give TransactionScope a try but it's not working. Here's what I'm doing; I have two transactions, one after the other, but both inside an outer transaction. Depending on which checkbox had been checked on the form, the code throws an exception either:
1. just before the first inner transaction's commit, or
2. between the two inner transactions, or
3. just before the second inner transaction's commit, or
4. just before the outer transaction's commit

The problem I'm getting is that, regardless of which checkbox I tick, the code executes as if no transactions were present. So in other words, the fact that I bug jump out of the try block because of an exception doesn't roll back any of the transactions.

Would appreciate some help. Below is my code for the little test application.

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (TransactionScope transactionOuter = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (TransactionScope transactionInner1 = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BasicTable (Value) VALUES ('Inside Inner Transaction 1')", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                if (checkBox_FailInner1.Checked)
                    throw (new Exception("Failed inside inner transaction 1"));

                transactionInner1.Complete();
            }

            if (checkBox_FailBetween.Checked)
                throw (new Exception("Failed between inner transactions"));

            using (TransactionScope transactionInner2 = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BasicTable (Value) VALUES ('Inside Inner Transaction 2')", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                if (checkBox_FailInnner2.Checked)
                    throw (new Exception("Failed inside inner transaction 2"));

                transactionInner2.Complete();
            }

            if (checkBox_FailOuter.Checked)
                throw (new Exception("Failed before outer transaction could commit"));

            transactionOuter.Complete();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}

MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

Comment: So, which exception have you got?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception, or at least not any exception which I'm not throwing myself. The point is, I'm expecting that, when I throw an exception at any of the four points where I do, it should ultimately result in the outer transaction rolling back and so none of the SQL commands should make permanent changes to the DB. That's not happening. No transaction in the above example rolls back ever, regardless of where I throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SqlConnection` enlists itself when it is opened. Only this point in time matters. The connection will be enlisted into whatever transaction is active at that time. You are opening the connection before any transaction is installed.

I believe you have a 2nd misunderstanding: It is not possible to nest transactions. You can only nest scopes. When you rollback an inner scope, the whole transaction is rolled back. All a `TransactionScope` does is set and manipulate `Transaction.Current`. Nothing more. The outermost scope installs a transaction. The inner scopes are mostly no-ops. All they do is provide a way to doom the transaction by not completing them.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. So it looks like the nesting order should be TransactionScope -> SqlConnection -> SqlCommand, as opposed to SqlConnection -> TransactionScope -> SqlCommand? This is different from the convention I've been used to (SqlConnection -> SqlTransaction -> SqlCommand).

Comment: Yes, correct. It is probably a good idea to read the top questions about transactionscope on SO to see what the (numerous) pitfalls are.